# Как узнать полный путь к папке, по окончанию и скопировать содержимое

Tags: python

Итак, в папке по этому пути `C:\Users\Server\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\Users` есть много папок, но мне нужно узнать название всех папок с окончанием -user, вот как они называются у меня `eg9no0brqmzrmfy6crh7e7fsy-user` и `rplc59ty0gmhfy4q8tgaz8gyt-user` мне по окончанию `-user` нужно узнать название папки, и скопировать её содержимое в другую папку

Comment: Наоборот. Нужно не по окончанию узнать название папки, а по названию папки узнать, оканчивается ли она на -user. Идёшь по каждой папке и смотришь, заканчивается ли она на - user

Comment: Очень хорошо, что вы поделились с нами тем, что вам нужно. А теперь рассажите, что именно у вас не получается. Код свой приведите.

Answer (score 2):

Всё посредством одной библиотеки os. Да, понимаю, что примение os.system является не очень хорошим тоном, но питоновская работа с копированием папок просто ужасна. Так что это лучше и понятней. Копирование папок здесь для Linux. В Windows чуть по-другому

```
import os

BASE_DIR = '/Ваша папка/'
TARGET_DIR = '/Ваша папка назначения/'

all_dirs = [x[1] for x in os.walk(BASE_DIR)][0]

user_dirs = list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith('-user'), all_dirs)) 
user_dirs = list((BASE_DIR + x) for x in user_dirs)

# Для Linux
for dir_ in user_dirs:
    os.system(f'cp -r {dir_} {TARGET_DIR}')

# Для Windows
for dir_ in user_dirs:
    os.system(f'xcopy {dir_} {TARGET_DIR}')
```